# check from which script require is

Tags: php

I've got few scripts, which use `require` to the same script (it is main configration script). Can I determine somehow which script used `require`, and depends on it load specific configuration from main file?
I think that it cant be done, but it worth a shoot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could set some parameters before the `require` call, and then read them to determine what to load.

Or you could use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`, but it's a messy variable.

Comment: oh..you mean for example: `<?define ('test','true');require('common.php')?>` and in common.php set `<?if(test){...}?>` ? hmmm..thats interesting thanks!

Comment: That's not quite what I had in mind, but I guess that could work. What I was thinking of is more `<?php $config = Array("core","login"); require("common.php");?> and in common.php have `<?php foreach($config as $toload) {/* load based on $toload */} ?>`

Comment: Yeah, that would work. If you had `define("FROMFILE", "file1");`, `define("FROMFILE", "file2");`, `define("FROMFILE", "file3");` etc, you could easily detect which file it came from in common.php. However, it's not how most people would suggest to do it.

Comment: Personally I'd just use a variable instead of defining a constant. Variables are passed into and out of a require'd file.

Comment: yeah, thanks I didn't know that, but variables could be overwritten so in my opinion its better to set up a constant assuming that it will be a configure file.